# How to disabled the Enhance Profile User in salesforce?

Tags: apex, profile

Why I am not getting the standard view and why getting the below view ?

I tried to change `User Interface` --> `Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface` --> disabled it, bit it did not work. Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you editing a permission set or a profile?

Comment: Profile. But dont know how to get the standard view?

Comment: Unchecking that box in the User Interface section should do it. It works for me. The reason I asked about permission sets is that they always use the new interface.

Comment: Could you please paste screen shot ? Its not working for me.. On Dev its working... On SIT same setting did not work

Answer (score 3):

As part of spring 18 pre-release , there is an option under manage users called user management settings , disable the enhanced profile from that , it should work .